# No negative terminal in power supply

Tags: power, serial, roomba

I'm working on a project that relies on the Roomba vaccum cleaner's [reference document](https://www.irobot.lv/uploaded_files/File/iRobot_Roomba_500_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) (shown below), there are two positive terminals and 2 ground terminals. I'd like to understand:

1. Why there isn't a negative terminal, only positive and ground (this isn't a typo, I measured the +ve-ground terminals with a multimeter).
2. Why there are two positive and two grounds instead of just one each (couldn't a user easily break a single terminal into two if he needed to?).

Please refer me if this question already has answers elsewhere; my google-fu may not be up to the mark.

[image: serial design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart shows that the GND pins are the battery return (in this case the negative side of the battery).

Two pins are used for each of Vpwr and GND for the following reasons.

1. Current carrying capacity of one pin is not enough.
2. Redundant connections for reliability increase.
3. Allow for continued operation even if one pin breaks off.

Answer (score 1):

The doubled + and Gnd pins may be to allow for greater currents that one pin can safely handle.

GND will be the negative terminal of the battery or power supply - in most circuits "Ground" is the most negative terminal in the circuit.